# Are spells that must overcome Spell Resistance worthwhile?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, wrath-of-the-righteous

Is it worth using or focusing on spells that allow SR in a campaign that is rife with Spell Resistance enemies, such as Wrath of the Righteous?

In particular spells like Spear of Purity and Holy Smite cry out to be used against Demons, but allow spell resistance.

Answer (score 3):

You are fine as long as you beat SR reliably. If not (and if you don't want to invest in that), no-SR spells are generally better.

Quite a comprehensive list of ways to break through SR can be found [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/30467/how-can-i-overcome-spell-resistance). Your call if those are worth your while, the restrictions of your character are not listed.

As for [Spear of Purity](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateMagic/spells/spearOfPurity.html) - it packs quite a punch for 2nd level, SR and other limiting factors balance that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, specifically for Wrath of the Righteous, investing in ways to overcome SR is important and valuable. The vast majority of opponents have SR, and you will fight them both individually and en masse (e.g. army of dretches). My group is playing through WotR right now and our sorcerer has gotten a lot more punch out of investing in SR-defeating feats (Spell Penetration, Piercing Spell). Since the opponent list is packed with so many demons, it's safe and desirable to invest in things that are specifically effective against them - bypass DR, bypass SR, proc on evil foes only, etc.