# How do you roll against Spell Resistance?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, resistance

I've been searching how Spell Resistance work for days and I haven't found an answer.
What is the roll to pass the target's SR? I mean the DC would be the SR, but what do I add to my roll?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the *Pathfinder* SRD section defining [Spell Resistance](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Spell-Resistance):

> To affect a creature that has spell resistance, a spellcaster must make a caster level check (1d20 + caster level) at least equal to the creature's spell resistance.

So the bonus to the roll is your caster level.

Comment: There are also a number of feats and other things that can give you an additional bonus to this roll ([see the accepted answer here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/30467/how-can-i-overcome-spell-resistance?rq=1)), but those will be explicitly stated in the description of the thing.

Comment: @GreySage Yes, but in a question about the basics, we can presume that a feat that clearly says "This gives you a +4 bonus to overcome SR" doesn't need to be explained.